# Registration COM-Interop (.tlb) including Assembly (.dll) references

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, regasm, tlbexp

I'm trying to register my Classlib.dll for using COM interop with the regasm.exe tool.
In general this is not a problem.

like this: `> regasm.exe MyAsm.dll /tlb: MyAsm.tlb`

But now I use a .dll reference in my classlib project. The general registration still works but then the dll reference gets lost and the functions are useless.

I'm sure there is a simple solution for this as the automatic registration via VisualStudio Build settings works fine.

So how can I manually adjust my script?

My current approaches are:

1. uing the option: regasm /asmpath
2. use of the tools: Tlbexp.exe, Tlbimp.exe

My current information sources:

- [Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool)](https://github.com/up1/docs-2/blob/master/docs/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool.md#regasmexe-assembly-registration-tool)
- [Registration free COM interop. assembly B reference assembly A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343718/registration-free-com-interop-assembly-b-reference-assembly-a)
- [Registration-Free COM Interop and Dependent Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644779/registration-free-com-interop-and-dependent-assemblies)

Since the documentaries are unfortunately very limited and I am new to the COM topic it would be great if you could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by _"But now I use a .dll reference in my classlib project...dll reference gets lost"_?  Which DLL?  Which classlib?   If you are talking about project B depending on project A (your COM library) you should be adding a COM reference to A not file reference and not a project reference.  Otherwise you get into pathing problems, something that COM doesn't use as a first class citizen.  COM references are via the registry and COM clients need not know where the DLL is located

Comment: I am using a dll wich provides funktions of the Dijkstra Algorithm (by Mateusz Mazurek)

Comment: <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;net40</TargetFrameworks>
    <Version>1.2.1</Version>
    <Authors>Mateusz Mazurek</Authors>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/matiii/Dijkstra.NET</RepositoryUrl>

Comment: "If you are talking about project B depending on project A (your COM library) you should be adding a COM reference to A not file reference and not a project reference. Otherwise you get into pathing problems, something that COM doesn't use as a first class citizen. COM references are via the registry and COM clients need not know where the DLL is located" Yes that's exactly right !

Comment: Right now I am trying to add the COM reference in my project..

Comment: You forgot the `/codebase` option.  Without it, you must install the DLL into the GAC so it can be found.  Which is a good idea on the user's machine, not on yours.

Comment: FYI: the source code from the referenced dll A is not 100% COM compatible, there are several warnings e.g. that generic types are found during manual registration.

> regasm.exe Dijkstra.NET.dll /tlb: Dijkstra.NET.tlb /codebase

Maybe it is also interesting, that in project A no target framework is and the automatic COM-interop registration is not selectable.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thats right. Is it easier to register assemblies in GAC?

Comment: so after I registered the assembly (according to the VS dev prompt) with:
> regasm.exe Dijkstra.NET.dll /tlb: Dijkstra.NET.tlb /codebase

I cannot find it in my VS COM references. Maybe I am missing something or have a mistake in my thinking. 

Do I have to add the COM data annotation like [ComVisible(true)] etc. in the source code? Usually if I don't have the source code and only the dll it should work as well, right? And after all, VS does it automatically when I choose it in the build options and use the Assembly via file reference.